# Access Public Function Form and Control Parameters

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, parameter-passing

I set up a public function.  It is meant to lock and gray a date control, unless its corresponding combo box control is set to a (bound) value of 2. I made this a public function, so I can call it on load of the form, on current, which fires when the form is navigated back or forth, and when the combo changes.  I also have to do this for 2 sets of paired combos and date controls, so having it in a function makes it easier to call for any form/control pairing, when I need to.

This is the public function:

```
Public Function DateFieldStatus(frm As Form, fkctl As Control, dtctrl As Control)
'Combo Status Values
'ID Combo
'1 =  not ok
'2 =  ok
'3 =  not ok

Select Case frm.fkctl
    Case 2
        frm.dtctrl.Locked = False
        frm.dtctrl.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Case Else
        frm.dtctrl.Locked = True
        frm.dtctrl.ForeColor = RGB(214, 214, 214)
End Select
frm.dtctrl.Requery

End Function
```

I have it set to call on load of the main form like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If DCount("ID", "tblMainTable") = 0 Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    End If
    Me.FirstControl.SetFocus
    DateFieldStatus Me.Form, Me.FKDropDown1, Me.dtDateControl1
End Sub
```

When Launch the main form, I get the following error:

Run-time error '2465':
Application-defined or object-defined error

When I debug, it hightlights this line of the public function:

```
Select Case frm.fkctl
```

I'm assuming it doesn't like me combining a form parameter with a control parameter.

Is that not something you can do?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is public function behind the form or in a standalone module?

Comment: standalone module. It's a public function not set in the form module.

Answer (score 3):

`frm.fkctl` is looking for a control named "fkctl" on the form, and not finding it obviously.

You don't need to pass `frm` to the function at all - the control object `fkctl` is sufficient to address the control.

Simply do:

```
Select Case fkctl.Value
```

and it will work.

You *could* do

```
frm(fkctl.Name)
```

but it would be kinda silly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I realized I didn't need to declare the form. I declare the control, and when I call the function, the form is .  Here is the final solution:

Public Function -

```
Public Function SmokerStatus(fkctl As Control, dtctrl As Control)
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response
'ID Combo
'1 =  not ok
'2 =  ok
'3 =  not ok

    Msg = "You have changed the option status" & vbCrLf & _
    "to a status that doesn't require an option date." & vbCrLf & _
    "The corresponding option date has a value. " & vbCrLf & _
    "If you would like to delete that date, click yes, otherwise click no, and we will undo."
    Style = vbYesNo
    Title = "Option Date Only Applies to PAST Option Status"

Select Case fkctl
    Case 2
        dtctrl.Locked = False
        dtctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Case Else
        If Nz(dtctrl, "") = "" Then
            dtctrl.Locked = True
            dtctrl.BackColor = RGB(214, 214, 214)
        Else
            Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
            If Response = vbYes Then
                dtctrl.Value = ""
                dtctrl.Locked = True
                dtctrl.BackColor = RGB(214, 214, 214)
            Else
                fkctl.Undo

            End If
        End If
End Select
dtctrl.Requery

End Function
```

Here is an example of calling it -

```
OptionStatus Me.FKOptionCombo, Me.dtOptionDate
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: That's what I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: yes, that is close. I just wanted to provide the complete function for others to be able to use.

Comment: That's all fine and well, but 1) I figured out the answer, before that was posted, and 2) I wanted to post the full solution, so others could be helped.